# Как записать результаты регулярного выражения в список? C#

Tags: c#, json, регулярные-выражения

Как вывести все значения, которые подходят после регулярного выражения. В переменной лежат эти значения.

```
[
    {"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.03416500"},
    {"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.01672200"},
    {"symbol":"BNBBTC","price":"0.00349860"},
    {"symbol":"NEOBTC","price":"0.00238600"},
    {"symbol":"QTUMETH","price":"0.01870700"},
    {"symbol":"EOSETH","price":"0.03303200"},
    {"symbol":"SNTETH","price":"0.00015567"},
]
```

Код такой:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{).*?(?=})");
Match match = regex.Match(str);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\gamen\\source\\repos\\WindowsFormsApp3\\WindowsFormsApp3\\questionAnswers.txt", $"{str}");
```

Как вывести в текстовый документ после обработки регулярки все значения (результаты) построчно?

Comment: Это не надо парсить регулярками, это надо распарсить как json.

Comment: json парсить регуляркой - такое себе удовольствие

Comment: Что значит "построчно"? На одной строке должно быть ETHBTC, а на другой 0.03416500?

Comment: Нет, то что в скобках {"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.03416500"} на одной строке. Это в регулярке прописано, просто как вывести все результаты в текстовый документ. Чтобы потом удобно было брать

Comment: По поводу регулярок и JSON Вам уже сказали, так что спрошу ещё вот что: в чем смысл интерполяции в Вашем примере? (`$"{str}"`)

Answer (score 2):

Это не надо парсить регулярками, это надо распарсить как json. Подключите Json.Net и распарсите:

```
var request = @"[{""symbol"":""ETHBTC"",""price"":""0.03416500""},{""symbol"":""LTCBTC"",""price"":""0.01672200""},{""symbol"":""BNBBTC"",""price"":""0.00349860""},{""symbol"":""NEOBTC"",""price"":""0.00238600""},{""symbol"":""QTUMETH"",""price"":""0.01870700""},{""symbol"":""EOSETH"",""price"":""0.03303200""},{""symbol"":""SNTETH"",""price"":""0.00015567""}]";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data[]>(request);
var lines = data.Select(x => $"{x.Symbol} - {x.Price}");
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\123.txt", lines);
```

Где Data:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в вашем случае - как-то так:

```
var request = @"[{""symbol"":""ETHBTC"",""price"":""0.03416500""},{""symbol"":""LTCBTC"",""price"":""0.01672200""},{""symbol"":""BNBBTC"",""price"":""0.00349860""},{""symbol"":""NEOBTC"",""price"":""0.00238600""},{""symbol"":""QTUMETH"",""price"":""0.01870700""},{""symbol"":""EOSETH"",""price"":""0.03303200""},{""symbol"":""SNTETH"",""price"":""0.00015567""}]";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{).*?(?=})");
var match = regex.Matches(request);
var lines = match.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\123.txt", lines);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]